# Unable into cd in to docker folder in /etc

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I'm learning about docker and I cannot seem to cd into the docker folder. I'm in etc folder and I'm trying to enter docker folder. It's blue text indicating it's a directory and I am able to enter into other blue directorys.

```
DIR_COLORS               makedumpfile.conf.sample  ssh
DIR_COLORS.256color      man_db.conf               ssl
DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor  mime.types                statetab
dnsmasq.conf             mke2fs.conf               statetab.d
dnsmasq.d                modprobe.d                subgid
docker                   modules-load.d            subuid
dracut.conf              motd                      sudo.conf
dracut.conf.d            mtab
```

I even try sudo cd docker.
But when I do this, the command line does nothing. I can ls the folder to see it's contents as below:

```
[user@bucephalus1 etc]$ sudo ls -al docker
total 16
drwx------.   2 root root   21 Mar 22 01:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 103 root root 8192 Mar 24 10:57 ..
-rw-------.   1 root root  244 Mar 22 01:07 key.json
```

But I cannot cd into docker as seen below:

```
[user@bucephalus1 etc]$ sudo ls -al docker
total 16
drwx------.   2 root root   21 Mar 22 01:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 103 root root 8192 Mar 24 10:57 ..
-rw-------.   1 root root  244 Mar 22 01:07 key.json
[user@bucephalus1 etc]$ sudo cd docker
[user@bucephalus1 etc]$
```

Does anyone have any idea on what is happening here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's normal and caused by the perms of the `/etc/docker` folder, as mentioned in your question:

```
[user@bucephalus1 etc]$ sudo ls -al docker
total 16
drwx------.   2 root root   21 Mar 22 01:07 .
(...)
```

because this folder belongs to root and have permissions 700.

You can instead do:

```
$ sudo su -
root:~# cd /etc/docker
root:/etc/docker#
```

Note however that modifying this folder might be error-prone and I'm unsure there's any use case requiring to do it.

Furthermore, this related answer from askubuntu.com gives more details on  `sudo su -`:
["sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used/376386#376386)

Comment: That's awesome @ErikMD. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bucephalus you're welcome, thanks for accepting my answer :) BTW I just edited my answer to add a link to a detailed explanation that may be of interest for you.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what the previous answer said, some background on the `cd` command:

When you `cd`, you should get this error:

```
$ cd /etc/docker/
bash: cd: /etc/docker/: Permission denied
```

When you `sudo cd /etc/docker/`, you are likely to get an error like this:

```
$ sudo cd /etc/docker
sudo: cd: command not found
```

But I guess there could be distros where you don't get that, and there actually is a `cd` binary. However, this binary should never work, because it would change the shell's child process' current directory (i.e. the current directory of the `cd` process), rather than the shell's current directory.

Maybe try doing `which cd` and executing the result. You will most likely see that you cannot change directories with this binary, even if you do not use `sudo`.

So use e.g. `sudo -s` to get a root shell and then `cd` around.

Comment: Yeah you might be right @sneep. This distro, centOS, doesn't seem to be giving me the "command not found" feedback. It just resets to the commandline prompt. Thanks for your help too.